# How to count the occurrence of a variable in log file matching a pattern/RegEx in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

I'm trying to store number occurrence of a value to count variable.

```
set ATTR_TO_VERIFY=W10SBRS
for /F "tokens=*" %%N  in ('findstr /r "^<.*^>.*%ATTR_TO_VERIFY%.*:" lofile.log ^| find /v "" /c') do set "COUNT=%%N"
echo %COUNT%
```

but count always give me value zero.

Comment: Change your search expression to `"<.*>.*%ATTR_TO_VERIFY%.*:"`

Comment: Thanks @mc nd. It worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex error that [@MCDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000037/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-log-file-matching-a-pattern-regex-i#comment71182358_42000037) pointed out in the comments is the one causing the trouble.
You can also do it without the `find /c`. To count the number of lines in the result of your `findstr` command the following should do:

```
set ATTR_TO_VERIFY=W10SBRS
for /F "tokens=*" %%N in ('findstr /n /r "<.*>.*%ATTR_TO_VERIFY%.*:" lofile.log') do set /a COUNT+=1
echo %COUNT%
```

The `FOR /F` automatically discards empty lines and lines starting with a `;` though. A way to solve this is to add the `/n` flag to the `findstr` and let `findstr` add the line numbers at the beginning of each matched line.

Comment: Just to be precise, the original code in the question does not *need* `tokens` nor `delims` clauses. The output of the `findstr` command is piped to a `find /v "" /c` command that directly returns the number of matching lines returned by the `findstr` command.

Comment: Of course...I had the `findstr /n` in mind that adds the line numbers instead! Terrible mistake. Thanks for remembering me